# Set hour fine until it reaches the max fine

Tags: java

The fine is RM150.00 for the first hour or part of an hour that the car is illegally parked.

Plus RM50.00 for every additional hour or part of an hour
that the car is illegally parked.

The maximum fine should be RM300.00.

**What should I do, if I want to set max fine is only until 300?**

```
public class ParkingTicket {
    private ParkedCar car;
    private PoliceOfficer police;
    private ParkingMeter meter;
    private double fine;
    private int min;
    private double firstfine = 150;
    private double hour_fine =50;
    private double max_fine = 300;

    public ParkingTicket() {
        car=null;
        police=null;
        fine=0;
        min=0;   
    }

    public void CalTotalFine() {
        int time = car.getParkMin()- meter.getMinutesPurchased();

        if(time < 60) {
            fine=firstfine;
        } else {
            fine= firstfine+ (hour_fine*(time/60));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `car = null; police = null; fine = min = 0;` are all already done for you, by the way... Putting those in the constructor is redundant

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the fine never exceeds the `max_fine`, you can add a check after evaluating the fine as :

```
if (fine > max_fine) {
    fine = max_fine;
}
```

and further use/return the value of `fine`.

Comment: does that means i add one more if after the else statement ??

Comment: @diu 1997 Yes, you can to check.

Comment: Ermm .... whose homework is this again?  @diu_1997 - you need to be learning here ... not asking people to spoon-feed you answers.  Read what the answer says.  Understand it.  Apply the knowledge.

Comment: Could just have `fine = Math.min(fine, max_fine)`

Answer (score 0):

The `fine` is what you call a calculated value. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to store it as a field.

If you want to cap it, then you can use the `Math.min()` method.

```
public static final double MIN_FINE = 150;
public static final double MAX_FINE = 300;
public static final double HOURLY_RATE = 50;

public double getFine() {
    int time = car.getParkMin()- meter.getMinutesPurchased();

    double fine = 0;
    if(time < 60) {
        fine = MIN_FINE;
    } else {
        fine = MIN_FINE + (time/60)*HOURLY_RATE;
    }

    // return the smallest of these values
    return Math.min(fine, MAX_FINE);
}
```